How to resolve 'nodemon app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting' error in Node.js?
Problem
When I attempt to run my Node.js application using nodemon, it crashes immediately after starting, displaying the error: "[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting." I've tried restarting the app and ending tasks in the task manager, as well as checking if the port was occupied by using XAMPP and changing the port number, but none of these actions resolved the issue.
What I tried

Restarted the application and the system
Checked for port conflicts using XAMPP and changed the port to 3306
Reviewed logs for specific error messages but didn't find any additional clues

Environment

Operating System: Windows
Nodemon version: 2.0.19
Relevant part of package.json:

    {
      "scripts": {
        "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server"
      }
    }

server.js
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const passport = require('passport');

connectDB();

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
}

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`);
});

db.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dbConfig = require('./dbconfig');

const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        const conn = await mongoose.connect(dbConfig.database, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useFindAndModify: false
        });
        console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
};

module.exports = connectDB;


Expected Outcome
I expect the application to continue running without crashing, with nodemon watching for file changes.
Actual Outcome
The application crashes immediately upon startup with the nodemon error message, and no further file changes are detected.
Question
What could be causing this immediate crash, and how can I resolve it to ensure nodemon properly monitors file changes without crashing?

This is normal behavior when your app is crashing. Can you add the code of server.js? Better yet - add the error message as seen in the console...

Yes, give me a sec

Now, you can see it

I'm sorry, now you can see the complete code

So it's the connection to database. Check credentials and stuff. Maybe it's in the file config/db.js but most likely it's in .env file

Hello, I'm stuck on this, I updated the db.js file, so you can see it and hopefully solve this issue
